# Twitter bootstrap grid not aligning

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

I'm having issue getting my grid to align correctly. Here is the HTML

```
<div class="span6" id="content">

        <!-- Category 2 is Programming category. -->

        <?php $programming_posts = get_posts('2'); ?>

        <div class="row-fluid">

            <?php foreach($programming_posts as $key => $post){ ?>

            <div class="span6 well well-small" id="post-preview">

                <?php echo $post->post_excerpt;?>

            </div>

            <?php }?>

        </div>

    </div>
```

Here is the CSS

```
#post-preview{
border: 1px solid rgba(140,140,140,1);
border-radius: 2px;
max-height: 135px;
min-height: 135px;
margin-bottom: 5px;
```

}

As you can see the first row is not aligned with the rows that comes after it. The first row is the row with the right alignment. I'm not sure how to fix this?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You html structure is bad as a `row-fluid` can have only maximum of 12 columns, ie in this case two `<div class="span6 well well-small" id="post-preview">` elements. But in your case you are adding all `post-preview` divs to a single `row-fluid`

Your html must be structure should be like

```
<div class="row-fluid">
    <div class="span6 well well-small" id="post-preview1">
    </div>
    <div class="span6 well well-small" id="post-preview2">
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row-fluid">
    <div class="span6 well well-small" id="post-preview1">
    </div>
    <div class="span6 well well-small" id="post-preview2">
    </div>
</div>
```

Also the [id should be unique in a document](http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110525/elements.html#the-id-attribute), you have many `div`s with id `post-preview` because of the loop

Comment: I see I created a condition inside the loop that creates a new row each two posts. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Approach A:

Since you have 4 blocks, you can use `span3` class:

```
<div class="span3 well well-small" id="post-preview">
    <?php echo $post->post_excerpt;?>
</div>
```

Approach B:

If you want to keep the width and only display a pair of blocks in one line, then you can split pairs of divs into separate `row-fluid` (PHP code is just for reference):

```
<div class="row-fluid">
    <div class="span6 well well-small" id="post-preview1">
        <?php echo $post->post_excerpt;?>
    </div>
    <div class="span6 well well-small" id="post-preview2">
        <?php echo $post->post_excerpt;?>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row-fluid">
    <div class="span6 well well-small" id="post-preview1">
        <?php echo $post->post_excerpt;?>
    </div>
    <div class="span6 well well-small" id="post-preview2">
        <?php echo $post->post_excerpt;?>
    </div>
</div>
```